# Pass argument to callback?

Tags: python

I'm working on my first python script. I want to use a variable within a callback-function:

```
def run(self, edit):
    gitFolder = os.path.basename(gitRoot)
    #Get branch
    self.run_command(['git', 'rev-parse','--abbrev-ref','HEAD'], self.branchDone)


def branchDone(self, result):
    build =  "./Build-Release.ps1 " + gitFolder + " " + result +" -Deploy;"
    print build
```

How do I make gitFolder available to the method branchDone?

Comment: return gitFolder - after `self.run_command(...)` in your `run(...)` function definition. try that. Also, you can add gitFolder as an argument in your `branchDone(self,result,gitFolder)` where you can pass it in. Otherwise, just declare gitFolder globally, and use it in both functions.

Comment: nope, File ".\Panagora.py", line 40, in branchDone
NameError: global name 'gitFolder' is not defined

Comment: I would guess it's because the return has not executed when branchDone is run.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using global variables in a function other than the one that created them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply return `gitFolder` from `run` and call `run` in `branchcode`
Try this:-

```
def run(self, edit):
    gitFolder = os.path.basename(gitRoot)
    #Get branch
    self.run_command(['git', 'rev-parse','--abbrev-ref','HEAD'], self.branchDone)
    return gitFolder

def branchDone(self, result):
    build =  "./Build-Release.ps1 " + run() + " " + result +" -Deploy;" #run() returns gitfolders
    print build
```

There is another way

```
   def run(self, edit):
        self.gitFolder = os.path.basename(gitRoot)
        #Get branch
        self.run_command(['git', 'rev-parse','--abbrev-ref','HEAD'], self.branchDone)


    def branchDone(self, result):
        build =  "./Build-Release.ps1 " + self.gitFolder + " " + result +" -Deploy;"
```

But it carries a problem that you need to execute the `run` function before executing `branchcode`, else `self.gitfolder` will be undefined and raise `Attribute error`.

Comment: I think that needs to be self.run(), but apart from that, great!

Comment: @KristofferNolgren i think i gave answer of your question, check the updated code.

Comment: Yes, this is great I just needed to wait before I could confirm!

Answer (score 1):

As I am observing, these are class methods, you can define a class attribute to share gitFolder across them.

```
def run(self, edit):
    self.gitFolder = os.path.basename(gitRoot)
    #Get branch
    self.run_command(['git', 'rev-parse','--abbrev-ref','HEAD'], self.branchDone)


def branchDone(self, result):
    build =  "./Build-Release.ps1 " + self.gitFolder + " " + result +" -Deploy;"
    print build
```

Comment: these are class methods, no reason to use global.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be using [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
def run(self, edit):
    gitFolder = os.path.basename(gitRoot)
    #Get branch
    callback = functools.partial(self.branchDone, gitFolder)
    self.run_command(['git', 'rev-parse','--abbrev-ref','HEAD'], callback)

def branchDone(self, gitFolder, result):
    build =  "./Build-Release.ps1 " + gitFolder + " " + result +" -Deploy;"
    print build
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need `branchDone` except for as a callback, consider defining it as a closure inside `run`:

```
from subprocess import check_output

def run_command(command, callback):
    callback(check_output(command).strip())

class Foo(object):
    def run(self, edit):
        gitFolder = "some_magic"
        def branch_done(result):
            print "./Build-Release.ps1 " + gitFolder + " " + result + " -Deploy;"
        run_command(['git', 'rev-parse','--abbrev-ref','HEAD'], branch_done)

Foo().run("edit")
```